# Using d3 data properties to set inner HTML to an img link

Tags: image, d3.js, innerhtml, src

I'd like to  be able to pass in an img src to inner html in a web application I'm building.

Here's an example of one item in my data:

```
{"ArtistImage": "https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8697643.jpeg", "Address": "7000 Coliseum Wy, Oakland, CA 94621", "Artist": "Shawn Mendes"}
```

And the HTML I'm trying to insert the image:

```
<li>
    <a id="test" href="#">Image</a>
</li>
```

And the JavaScript to dynamically change the inner HTML based on which data point I'm hovering over.

```
d3.selectAll(".events")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {        
              document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<img src=\"d.ArtistImage\" width=\"400px\" height=\"150px\">";
          })
```

But it's reading a 404 error, image not found.  How to I get this bit of JavaScript to pass the link in d.ArtistImage as a string to the inner HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this...

```
"<img src=\"d.ArtistImage\" width=\"400px\" height=\"150px\">"
```

... you are saying that the `src` of that image is literally `d.ArtistImage`, which is clearly incorrect.

You can do it easily with template literals. Or simply concatenating the strings:

```
"<img src='" + d.ArtistImage + "' width='400px' height='150px'>"
```

Finally, you don't need to use `document.getElementById` in a D3 code. One could argue that `document.getElementById` is faster than a D3 selection (which internally uses `document.querySelector`), but the difference is not significant and, what's more important, this is not idiomatic. Just use a D3 selection with `html`, which uses `innerHTML` internally:

```
d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseover", function(d) {        
    d3.select("#test").html("<img src='" + d.ArtistImage + "' width='400px' height='150px'>");
})
```